# VBA code to set date format for a specific column as "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which I specify the date (in mm/dd/yyyy) in a textbox and I want to set this value for column A in yyyy-mm-dd format.  I have the following code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", "A50000").Value = TextBox3.Value
Sheet1.Range("A2", "A50000") = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

...and when I run the macro, the date is still in mm/dd/yyyy format.

How can I change this so that it is in the format I want??  I've been trying many kinds of code researched through google and nothing will set the format the way I want it.

Any help will be appreciated...

EDIT: Full code from OP's comment below:

```
 Workbooks.Add
 Range("A1") = "Acctdate"
 Range("B1") = "Ledger"
 Range("C1") = "CY"
 Range("D1") = "BusinessUnit"
 Range("E1") = "OperatingUnit"
 Range("F1") = "LOB"
 Range("G1") = "Account"
 Range("H1") = "TreatyCode"
 Range("I1") = "Amount"
 Range("J1") = "TransactionCurrency"
 Range("K1") = "USDEquivalentAmount"
 Range("L1") = "KeyCol"
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", "A50000").Value = TextBox3.Value
 Sheet1.Range("A2", "A50000").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the range's `NumberFormat` property to force the format of the range like this:

```
Sheet1.Range("A2", "A50000").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Comment: @KristinaKotonika - what version of Excel are you using?  I tested this in both Excel 2003 and Excel 2007 without issue.  Did you call `Sheet1.Range("A2", "A50000") = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")` first?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010.  At first, I didn't call the code you mentioned above and when I added it, it still didn't change anything.  Before this, I am opening up the file and then clearing data, but I don't how this could effect the format in any way...

Comment: `Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\Data\...\LedgerAmount.xlsx"
Rows(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows.Count - 1).ClearContents`

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Excel 2010 to test with.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I'll try to play around with it

Comment: To anyone...Is there any way to select the location when formatting the date?  I noticed that the format yyyy-mm-dd is not available for the English (US) location but is available for other countries...

Comment: just tried it in excel 2010, and it works. also formatted a cell using custom formatting, recorded it as a macro, and got `Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"`, and I'm in the US

Comment: hmmm I don't know what the problem is then...I'm going to try to open a new workbook and start from scratch to see if that changes anything because other than that IDK what else to change.  Thank you for letting me know that it can work though.

Comment: no luck, here is my code: `Workbooks.Add
    
Range("A1") = "Acctdate"
    
Range("B1") = "Ledger"
    Range("C1") = "CY"
    Range("D1") = "BusinessUnit"
    Range("E1") = "OperatingUnit"
    Range("F1") = "LOB"
    Range("G1") = "Account"
    Range("H1") = "TreatyCode"
    Range("I1") = "Amount"
    Range("J1") = "TransactionCurrency"
    Range("K1") = "USDEquivalentAmount"
    Range("L1") = "KeyCol"
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", "A50000").Value = TextBox3.Value
    Sheet1.Range("A2", "A50000").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"`

Answer (score 11):

You are applying the formatting to the workbook that has the code, not the added workbook.  You'll want to get in the habit of fully qualifying sheet and range references.  The code below does that and works for me in Excel 2010:

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
With wb.Sheets(1)
    .Range("A1") = "Acctdate"
    .Range("B1") = "Ledger"
    .Range("C1") = "CY"
    .Range("D1") = "BusinessUnit"
    .Range("E1") = "OperatingUnit"
    .Range("F1") = "LOB"
    .Range("G1") = "Account"
    .Range("H1") = "TreatyCode"
    .Range("I1") = "Amount"
    .Range("J1") = "TransactionCurrency"
    .Range("K1") = "USDEquivalentAmount"
    .Range("L1") = "KeyCol"
    .Range("A2", "A50000").Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
    .Range("A2", "A50000").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Even if this works for you, I'd mark @littebobbytables as the answer, since it was the correct response to the question as posted at that time.

Answer (score 2):

It works, when you use both lines:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C1", "C20000") = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("C1", "C20000").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheet1.Range("A2", "A50000").NumberFormat = "yyyy\-mm\-dd"
```

You need to add backlash (    \    ) to print the next character as literal character.

Excel recognise (-) as date separator symbol. So, Excel use your computer default date separator which is (/). Some region uses (-) as default date separator. If your excel cannot display the symbol, just add backlash infront of it.