# Date format doesn't accepts zero at the beginning

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have below is made in order to accepts only date format like this: 12.10.2018. Usually, in the specific column, people will copy-paste data from another sheet, so I made the code to change the format of the date when values such as 12-10-2018 or 12/10/2018 will be pasted to 12.10.2018.

The code works just fine, but it seems that there is a problem. When the date is written or pasted like this: 02-02-2018 or 02/02/2018, the - and / are changed to . which is great, but the format also deletes my zeros, which I don't want that, so it turns into 2.2.2018. Why is not changing to 02.02.2018?

The date format on the column A is also set as "14.03.2014" so i don't see the problem. Why the 0 is not kept? Thanks in advance.

Note: the format in the cell must always have the length 10: i.e. 02.02.2018

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim date As Range

 For Each date In ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a1000")
  If Not IsEmpty(date) Then
    date.Replace What:="/", Replacement:=".", MatchCase:=True

  End If
 Next

 Dim date1 As Range

 For Each date1 In ActiveSheet.Range("a1:a1000")
  If Not IsEmpty(date1) Then
    date1 .Replace What:="-", Replacement:=".", MatchCase:=True

  End If
 Next





Dim cellA As Range
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     For Each cellA In Target
         If Not Application.Intersect(cellA , Range("a1:a1000")) Is Nothing Then
           If Not IsNumeric(cellA .Value) Then
               cellA .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf cellA .Value = "" Then
               cellA .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        ElseIf Len(cellA .Value) <> 10 Then
                cellA .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        Else
           cellA .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
           End If
        End If
   Next cellA
   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you set the NumberFormat to what you want? [VBA code to set date format for a specific column as “yyyy-mm-dd”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12324368/1115360)

Comment: Tried that now. Instead of having setting it as "yyyy-mm-dd" I put it as "dd-mm-yyyy" but didn't work..

Comment: If changing the numberformat of the worksheet cell does not change the appearance of the value, then the value is text and NOT a real date.  If they are real dates, all you need to do is change the cell format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the .Replace method, you could do it as below:

```
Sub foo()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1000")
    If IsDate(c) Then
        c.Value = Format(c, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    End If
Next
End Sub
```