# how to change the date format of a cell displayed as yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column in which date is displayed in the format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss. I want to change the date format of that column. I am trying to insert another column and copy the data of that column in the new column by using format. Please find below my code.

```
last_Row = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert

For i = 2 To last_Row
lfd_value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value
lfd_val_upd = Format(lfd_value, dd/mm/yyyy)
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = lfd_val_upd
Next i
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12324190/1531971

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your Format with the following:

```
lfd_val_upd = Format(lfd_value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Or if your dates are not formatted as dates the the following should work:

```
lfd_val_upd = Format(CDate(lfd_value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

**EDIT:**

Try the following code, I've tested it and it works for me, an example date I tried is `2018/02/01 12:05:00`:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column B
ws.Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert

For i = 2 To LastRow
    lfd_value = ws.Range("C" & i)
    lfd_val_upd = Format(CDate(lfd_value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    ws.Range("B" & i).Value = lfd_val_upd
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Another possibility is that your dates are not formatted as they should, the following will pick the parts of the contents of the cell and then convert them parts to a date and enter that date into Column B as Text:

```
Sub foo2()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
ws.Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
For i = 2 To LastRow
    yearnumber = Mid(ws.Cells(i, 3), 7, 4)
    monthnumber = Mid(ws.Cells(i, 3), 4, 2)
    daynumber = Left(ws.Cells(i, 3), 2)
    LValue = DateSerial(yearnumber, monthnumber, daynumber)
    lfd_val_upd = Format(CDate(LValue), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    ws.Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
    ws.Range("B" & i).Value = lfd_val_upd
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Or use typed function Format$

Comment: When using format(lfd_value, "dd/mm/yyyy") ,  its displaying the date as 41:30,0 which is actually the mm:ss value of the cell. But when I click on the cell, its displaying the date as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. How shall I change the date format?

Comment: @user9351236 I've updated my answer, tested this and it works as expected, please try it and let me know if any issues. :)

Comment: @Xabier - Thanks. The second update works fine for me. :)