# Change date format when coping from workbook to another workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl module, and when i want to copy dates to workbook i had a a different result

```
data_sz = sh.cell(row = row, column = 2)
data_c1 = new_ws.cell(row = row, column = 7)
data_c1.value = data_sz.value
```

from cell value (data_sz): 2020-05-05, my copied value is: (data_c1) 2020-05-05 00:00:00 and i want to get rid off those time numbers.

Comment: ["VBA code to set date format for a specific column as 'yyyy-mm-dd'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324190/vba-code-to-set-date-format-for-a-specific-column-as-yyyy-mm-dd/12324368)

Answer (score 1):

Dates and times must always have a format, otherwise Excel just thinks they're numbers. openpyxl defaults to ISO-format.

When copying you can just copy the number format:

```
data_c1.number_format = data_sz.number_format
```